# Derivation of OLS Variance

Tags: regression, self-study, variance, least-squares

I stumbled over a rather simple result of OLS regression which is

$$
Var[\hat\beta] = \sigma^2(X^TX)^{-1}
$$
where $\sigma$ is the variance of the error term $u$ and $X$ is the regressor matrix.

I first just accepted the proof in my textbook but now I am thinking that it either uses sloppy notation or I am missing something. $\hat\beta$ is the estimated and $\beta$ is the true parameter (assuming unbiasedness).

It states that

\begin{align}
Var[\hat\beta] &= E[(\hat\beta - \beta)(\hat\beta-\beta)^T] \\
               &= E[(X^TX)^{-1}X^Tuu^TX(X^TX)^{-1}]         \\
               &=  (X^TX)^{-1}X^T E[uu^T] X(X^TX)^{-1}
\end{align}

but $X$ was only assumed to be exogenous and not non-stochastic. Under this assumption I think $X$ cannot be dragged outside the expectation operator.

Momentarily, I think that it should be $Var[\hat\beta|X]$ to make sense. Is that the case? My web research couldn't clarify this. I only found similar derivations to the above without further explainations.

Comment: This looks like frequentist statistics and thus data or observations should be random, not the inputs or regressors, shouldn't they? The data are random because there is random error added.

Comment: A couple of pages before this derivation the book authors state that  assuming $X$ as nonstochastic is "frequently not a reasonable assumption" . Therfore, this assumption was relaxed to exogeneity.

Comment: In section 6 of [this tutorial](http://web.stanford.edu/~mrosenfe/soc_meth_proj3/matrix_OLS_NYU_notes.pdf) it gives that the simplification only holds if $X$ is assumed non-stochastic.

Comment: This would support my assumption that if we assume only exogeneity the correct notation would have been $Var[\hat\beta|X]$ and not $Var[\hat\beta]$. But why is this fact skipped so often? Seems not correct to me.

Comment: It seems that under the assumptions usually made the usual estimate for the variance given that $X$ is fixed is also an unbiased estimate of the unconditional estimate when $X$ is random as is shown [here](http://thestatsgeek.com/2013/08/30/why-regression-inference-assuming-fixed-predictors-is-still-valid-for-random-predictors/). Maybe that helps.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are right that the conditional variance is not generally the same as the unconditional one. By the variance decomposition lemma, which says that, for r.v.s $X$ and $Y$

$$
Var(X)=E[Var(X|Y)]+Var[E(X|Y)]
$$
Translated to our problem,
$$
Var(\widehat{\beta})=E[Var(\widehat{\beta}|X)]+Var[E(\widehat{\beta}|X)]
$$
Now, using that OLS is conditionally unbiased (under suitable assumptions like exogeneity assumed here), we have
$$
E(\widehat{\beta}|X)=\beta 
$$
and thus
$$
Var[E(\widehat{\beta}|X)]=0,$$
as $\beta$ is a constant, so that
$$
Var(\widehat{\beta})=E[Var(\widehat{\beta}|X)]
$$
or
$$Var(\widehat{\beta})=E[\sigma^2(X'X)^{-1}]=\sigma^2E[(X'X)^{-1}].$$

Comment: Oh, just realized that this is pretty much what the link of @gwr says...

Comment: +1 I am only a *biased* Bayesian and thus have forgotten long ago about what unbiased estimators really are good for and thus had to use secondary material to answer anyways. As a pun: Your concise answer is better for the long run... :-)