# Can we derive the Variance of the least squares slope WITHOUT assuming that $X_i$s are fixed or deterministic?

Tags: regression, variance, least-squares, random-variable, regression-coefficients

Everywhere in the literature, I have seen that while deriving the variance of the least squares slope estimate $Var(\hat \beta_1) = \dfrac{\sigma ^2}{SS_{xx}}$, we always assume that $X_i$s are fixed i.e., they are deterministic in nature. Can we derive the variance formula without this assumption? (Assuming we already have the result $E(\hat \beta_1) = \beta_1$

Comment: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/183986/derivation-of-ols-variance/184015#184015

Comment: @ChristophHanck Thanks for the link. Do you mean that if $X_i$s are also random, then the formula for variance should be $\sigma^2 E(\dfrac{1}{SS_{xx}})$ instead of $\dfrac{\sigma ^2}{SS_{xx}}$?

Comment: Yes. An (unconditional) variance is a population parameter, hence a constant, and if the $X_i$ are random variables, so is $SS_{xx}$, so that it cannot be the unconditional variance.

Comment: @ChristophHanck Okay thanks a lot!