# is the $Var(\hat{\beta_1}|X)$ same as the variance of $Var(\hat{\beta_1})$ in simple linear regression?

Tags: regression, mathematical-statistics, inference, econometrics

Here are two captures from different videos on youtube, one obtains $Var(\hat{\beta_1})$, the other obtains $Var(\hat{\beta_1}|X)$ but they yields the same equations when the second capture further comments that $Var(\hat{\beta_1}|X)\neq Var(\hat{\beta_1})$

[image]

[image]

[capture1 vedio](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rODUBTRUV0U&t=509s&loop=0)

[capture2 vedio](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SFVwo-yr28M&loop=0)

Comment: See also https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/183986/derivation-of-ols-variance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In both videos, the speakers caution that *$X$ is assumed fixed*. When $X$ is assumed fixed, this means that there is no variation in $X$ and so $Var(\hat{\beta_1} | X) = Var(\hat{\beta_1})$. So in short, the answer to your question is "yes."

When the term "simple linear regression" is used, that assumption is normally invoked (whether implicitly or explicitly). The Wikipedia article on OLS provides a decent summary of this assumption: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinary_least_squares#Assumptions

Comment: Thank you for your reply. What about the second video also assert that$Var(\hat{\beta_1} | X) \neq Var(\hat{\beta_1})$? If $X$ is random, what is the $Var({\hat{\beta_1}})$?